# Checking for lazy loaded script promise

Tags: angular, google-maps

So let's say I'm async loading some script (google maps in my case) with a service, which will return a promise and resolve it on load finish.

I do this because I don't want to add the script to `index.html` (I need dynamic api key and I want to load the map script only if the user navigates to a component using the map).

How would I go about implementing some method which will work only if the script has finished loading?

Currently I can do something like this in `my-map.component.ts`:

```
ngOnInig() {
    this.promiseReturningScriptLoader();
}
```

...

```
async doSomethingWithMap() {
    await this.promiseReturningScriptLoader();

    // Actual mplementation
}
```

But does that mean I will have to await promise on the beginning of every public method? Doesn't seem pretty.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You should have a look into Angular Lazy Loading Modules https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules. Then you can load the entire component only if the user navigates there.